# Border Control from Copenhagen (Denmark) to Malmo (Sweden)

Tags: customs-and-immigration, borders, sweden, denmark, refugees

Has the asylum seeker/refugee situation in Sweden lead to any extra security checks or border checkpoints along this route?

I will be travelling from Copenhagen - Malmo and back in around a month so I was looking to be made aware of any extra things to be careful of.

I don't expect to have any trouble personally as I am an EU(Irish) citizen and both countries are in the Schengen Area, but I am curious as to the situation on this border.

Comment: I know there's loads of questions dealing with the Denmark-Sweden Schengen Area scenario. I'm specifically wondering if/how the refugee "crisis" has impacted on it.

Comment: Permanent immigration checkpoints were reintroduced at the Swedish sea borders and at the Øresundsbron November 12th, 2015 at 12pm and justified with the refugee situation. Here is the press release from the Swedish authorities: https://www.krisinformation.se/nyheter/2015/november/polisen-om-tillfalliga-granskontroller

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo However, the checks are only systematic on the bridge

Comment: @Coke Many of the new requirements introduced in 2015 were abolished in May 2017, so *now* only some of the new checkpoints are still manned permanently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The refugee crisis is indeed the main factor causing internal border checks to be introduced, after not having existed at the intra-Nordic land borders since the 1950s.

If taking the bus or car from Copenhagen to Malmö, you will be checked. If taking the train or ferry, it's hit or miss.

Comment: Thanks :). I don’t understand why somebody down-voted this. It answered my question..?

Comment: @Andre perhaps it was the gratuitous political interjection.

Comment: @phoog Of course, don't see what else it'd be.

Comment: Fair enough. I mean there probably wasn’t any need to put it in, but I don’t think it’s offensive.

Comment: I'm fascinated that some people prioritise my political views over the factual content of the answer I provide. How mature!

Comment: If you take the ferry in Helsingør to Helsingborg, you will have short passport control. There is no escaping.

Comment: @Steven Do you commute using it? I know someone who does and I'm told there's often no police at all, and when there is, they only stop a few cars at random.

Comment: @Coke I went as a passenger by foot. You needed to pass by a boot where they where 2 Border officers, it was also sunday. I was there as an tourist. So maybe you are right, I got luck to be checked.